# Efficiency problems about fog of war effect in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Sorry for my poor English.
I am busy making a game like Dota using Flash.
Unlike some little webgames , the fog of war is very complex----trees can block  one player's view rang,etc.
I think tile-based fog maybe a good idea.But the world in game is very large(3000*3000 or more),and the tile size is about 32*16 pixels and the view size is about 1920*1000 pixels.So there are too many small tiles in screen.Though I build every tile as a bitmap(using the same bitmapdata) and dont't build fogs out of screen ,but the frame rate is still so slow when scroll screen.
Does anyone can help me?

PS:
I want to use new Flash API to render these in GPU.But molehill allow combine normal stage(include my game world) and stage3D( include my fog of war ) in screen?

Comment: About your PS... You can draw Flash display list objects over the top of molehill rendered graphics, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

What technique do you use for hiding the non-visible parts of the map - scroll rect or mask? You should use scroll rect if you are using masks as it is far more performant than masks (here's an article http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/11/understanding_d.html). You should also consider using some game engine (Flixel and PushButtonEngine are fine examples).

Comment: Thank you,sir.But I don't think my large map is the key problem.Because if I remove the fog and scroll the map, the frame rate can up to 24/24. I just put the map bitmap in a sprite container and control the x and y.

Comment: If you are not using scroll rect that's definitely impacting the performance because even if parts of your bitmap are off-screen they are still rendered by flash player.

Comment: How exactly are you constructing the fog of war?

Comment: 1.I draw a unit shape(diamond) 2.I build a bitmapdata 3.I use bitmapdata.draw function to change the shape to a bitmapdata. At last ,new bitmap(bitmapdata),the bitmap is my final fog tile.

Comment: I calculate the view range in the screen and change the unit fog tile's alpha(1,0.5,0). When I move the map,I don't remove or new any fog tile ,just move the fog tiles on the screen edge which will disappear soon to another edge which will appear soon.